# Reading an existing object in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ssis

The script below is from the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-deploy-powershell?view=sql-server-ver15

The line where it creates a new object. How can I read an existing object instead of creating a new object? Because `New-Object` tries to create a new folder and I get an error because the folder already exists. I just want to  read the existing object so I can use the methods.

For people who know SSIS: I want to deploy to an existing folder so I need to adjust the script so it does not try to create the folder.

```
# Variables
$TargetInstanceName = "localhost\default"
$TargetFolderName = "Project1Folder"
$ProjectFilePath = "C:\Projects\Integration Services Project1\Integration Services Project1\bin\Development\Integration Services Project1.ispac"
$ProjectName = "Integration Services Project1"

# Get the Integration Services catalog
$catalog = Get-Item SQLSERVER:\SSIS\$TargetInstanceName\Catalogs\SSISDB\

# Create the target folder
New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.CatalogFolder" ($catalog, 
$TargetFolderName,"Folder description") -OutVariable folder
$folder.Create()
```

Comment: From `$catalog.Folders` I imagine :) or perhaps `Get-Item SQLSERVER:\SSIS\$TargetInstanceName\Catalogs\SSISDB\Folders\$TargetFolderName`

Comment: Comment above helped solve the problem.